# SQLite query with subquery performance

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a next SQL  query to Sqlite database:

```
SELECT * FROM messages   WHERE type IN (3) AND modem_id IN( 
    SELECT device_id FROM client_devices WHERE client_id=0 AND device_id IN (7368859)) 
ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Where the subquery brings the single data row. The query executes on  my data about 7sec. The separate subquery executes less then 1ms.  But if I get rid subquery and pass this single modem_id direct to  query :

```
SELECT * FROM messages   WHERE type IN (3) AND modem_id IN( 7368859) 
ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
```

the query executes less then 50ms.

What I am misunderstood?

UPD:
The query :

```
SELECT * FROM  messages   WHERE  type IN (3) AND modem_id IN( SELECT 7368859) ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
```

executes 7sec. And the query

```
SELECT * FROM  messages   WHERE  type IN (3) AND modem_id IN(7368859) ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Executes 44ms. 
That is the problem.

UPD:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stations` (
    `bs_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `online_status` INTEGER,
    `dl_status` INTEGER,
    `status_duration`   INTEGER,
    `noise` INTEGER,
    `temperature`   INTEGER,
    `dl_busyness`   INTEGER,
    `dl_aver_busyness`  INTEGER,
    `bs_state`  INTEGER,
    `rev_list`  TEXT,
    `ul_bitrates`   TEXT,
    `dl_bitrates`   TEXT,
    `ul_base_freqs` TEXT,
    `dl_base_freqs` TEXT,
    `last_hb_time`  INTEGER,
    `bs_type`   TEXT,
    `timezone_offset`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (10800),
    PRIMARY KEY(`bs_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `radiomodems` (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `batch_id`  INTEGER,
    `nbfi_ver`  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `hw_type`   TEXT,
    `protocol`  TEXT,
    `dl_strength`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 26,
    `ul_messages_per_ack`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `dl_messages_per_ack`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `ul_base_freq`  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 868800000,
    `dl_base_freq`  INTEGER DEFAULT 446000000,
    `dl_mode`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `dl_phy`    TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DL_PSK_200',
    `dl_num_of_retries` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
    `key`   TEXT,
    `bs_data`   TEXT,
    `ul_bitrates`   TEXT,
    `dl_bitrates`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `modem_id`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `station_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `time_detected` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `time_saved`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `type`  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    `iterator`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `payload`   BLOB NOT NULL,
    `snr`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `rssi`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `freq`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `phy`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `comment`   TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `downlinks` (
    `tag_id`    TEXT,
    `modem_id`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `station_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    `payload`   BLOB NOT NULL,
    `flags` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    `status`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `posted_time`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now','utc')),
    `placeholder`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`tag_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients` (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `apikey`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `role`  INTEGER NUT DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_devices` (
    `client_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `device_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(`client_id`,`device_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`device_id`) REFERENCES `radiomodems`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `time4_idx` ON `messages` (
    `type`,
    `time_detected`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `time3_idx` ON `messages` (
    `type`,
    `modem_id`,
    `time_detected`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `time2_idx` ON `messages` (
    `type`,
    `station_id`,
    `time_detected`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `time1_idx` ON `messages` (
    `type`,
    `modem_id`,
    `station_id`,
    `time_detected`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `modem_id_idx` ON `radiomodems` (
    `id`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `dl_tag_id_idx` ON `downlinks` (
    `tag_id`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `dl_status_idx` ON `downlinks` (
    `status`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `client_dev_idx` ON `client_devices` (
    `device_id`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `batch_idx` ON `radiomodems` (
    `batch_id`
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `apikey_idx` ON `clients` (
    `apikey`
);
COMMIT;
```

Query plans:

```
explain query plan SELECT * FROM  messages   WHERE  type IN (3) AND modem_id IN( SELECT 7368859) ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE messages USING INDEX time4_idx (type=?)"
"0" "0" "0" "EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1"

explain query plan SELECT * FROM  messages   WHERE  type IN (3) AND modem_id IN(7368859) ORDER BY time_detected DESC LIMIT 1000
"0" "0" "0" "SEARCH TABLE messages USING INDEX time3_idx (type=? AND modem_id=?)"
```

UPD:
In my case 'modem_id IN ( * )' and 'type IN ( * )' both can be as scalars as vectors and depends on program logic, so  solution was makes 'type IN( * )' always  as vector,  some thing like 'type IN(-1,* )' after this all queries executes perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery in `type IN (SELECT ...)` could return an arbitrary number of rows, so the database assumes that there are many, and estimates that it is faster to look up `type` in that list, and not the other way around.

When you know that the subquery returns exactly one row, write it as a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#subq):

```
... WHERE type = (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: In my case 'modem_id IN ( * )' and 'type IN ( * )' both can be as scalars as vectors and depends on program logic, so  solution was makes 'type IN( * )' always  as vector,  some thing like 'type IN(-1,* )' after this all queries executes perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try rephrasing this as a `join`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m JOIN
     client_devices cd
     ON cd.device_id = m.modemId
WHERE m.type = 3 AND cd.client_id = 0 AND cd.device_id = 7368859
ORDER BY m.time_detected DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Based on your description, I suspect that indexes on `client_devices(client_id, device_id)` and `messages(modem_id, type)` would help the query.  The one snag is the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The indexes present on messages table, the clients_devices table is small, and also have client_id as primary key. By the way, the separate query on client_devicese executes extremely quick.

Comment: I have updated question, the simplest two queries take very different results.